# Not able to access Jenkins while

Tags: jenkins, vpn, windows-firewall

I want to implement Continuous integration in my organization. But the problem is SVN is in local network, all developers are allowed to check-in only in local network. But build and deployment setup is such that it needs to access client network which we connect over VPN.

So, when I launch Jenkins in local network I can check-out files from SVN, but cannot build.
When I connect to VPN and launch Jenkins, I cannot access SVN, but can use existing checked-out code for build and deployment.

Is there any firewall/network settings using which I can do both check-out and build in a single job?

Note: Jenkins installed on Windows 7, and use SVN plug-in available in Jenkins.